# What am I missing when trying to perform this multidimensional List insert?

Tags: c#, list, set, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a multidimensional List that can be accessed and set in the following way:

```
myObjectVar[1,2,3] = new MyObject();
```

I have overloaded `[,,]` in the following way, but the Inserts never get run.  What is the correct way to check to see if an index exists because the below code doesn't seem to be working.

```
public myObject this[int x, int y, int z] {
    get { 
    return _myObject[x][y][z]; 
}

    set { 
        if(_myObject.Count < x){
            _myObject.Insert(x, new List<List<myObject>>());
        }

        if(_myObject[x].Count < y){
            _myObject[x].Insert(y, new List<myObject>());
        }

        if(_myObject[x][y].Count < z){
            _myObject[x][y][z].Insert(z, value);    
        }
        else{
            _myObject[x][y][z] = value;    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it not work? Can you be more specific. Can you post a complete code example? This is only a fragment that is missing vital parts.

Comment: `_myObject[x][y][z].Insert(z, new myObject());` this is wrong. You are building an useless object. You should probably write `_myObject[x][y][z].Insert(z, value;` and put the `_myObject[x][y][z] = value;` in an else of this `if`

Comment: @xanatos, while building useless object is unnecessarily inefficient, it's not wrong.

Comment: @afuzzyllama: "below code doesn't seem to be working", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @svick Yeah... It's not WRONG... it's a little wrong :-) . It's only a useless side-effect. But it isn't the real problem of the code. And the problem is that there isn't a problem in the code :-)

Comment: Does `myObjectVar[1,1,1] = new MyObject();` work ? How is _myObject declared ?

Comment: @affuzzulama: please provide some code on MyObject type definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to create something like a multidimensional array where you don't have to specify bounds and that is expanded as you set the elements.

In that case, what is wrong with your code is that you use `Insert()`. That method can be used to insert items in the middle of an existing list, but not beyond. So, if you have empty list, you can't insert something at the position `2`.

If you want to do this, you have to expand the lists manually by calling `Add()` in a loop.

But if you are expecting very sparse structure (that is, most elements are not set), you should probably use something like `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, T>>>`.

Comment: I thought the point of the List was to be dynamically sizable?  Would I need to resize the list of the Count wasn't big enough?

Comment: The point of `List<T>` is that you can `Add()` as many items as you want to it and the underlying array will dynamically resize. But you can't insert items beyond the current end of the list.

Comment: I will try to use the Dictionary object.  Thanks!